# Why hover is not working in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to follow this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pradkumar_n/VpmbL/1159/) for my web application but somehow I don't obtain the results that I would like to get.

I would like that the text changes its colour when the mouse is over. Here is what I have done until now.

HTML code looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="menu"> 
       <ul>
          <a href="#"><li>AAA</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>BBB</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>CCC</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>DDD</li></a>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

My JQuery code:

```
$(function(){
        $('li').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        });
 });
```

My CSS code:

```
.highlight{
    color:green;
}
```

Any idea?

My [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/j6kmqydb/5/)

Comment: While i voted to close the question, i must say, that the question itself is not bad. It contains the relevant code and a problem statement. So I wonder if such questions should be downvoted or not.

Comment: Well, as @NicoO says, the question includes a fiddle, so why it was downvoted? This affects my points, that's incredible.

Comment: Most likely because it is not "useful" for future readers. Like you can read in the text of the reason for the closing of the question: **This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**. It's a matter of personal perspective I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because your HTML is invalid - the `a` element must be inside the `li`:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CCC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DDD</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('li a').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/j6kmqydb/6/)

Note that your fiddle did not include jQuery, and you can also shorten the code by using `toggleClass()`:

```
$('li a').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: oh Thxs so much, what a silly error :)